# Store a value locally as a dynamic trait type in Rust

Tags: rust

I have code that is somewhat like

```
trait Checker {
   fn check(&self, value: &str) -> bool;
}

struct ShortChecker {}
impl Checker for ShortChecker {
   fn check(&self, value: &str) -> bool {
      value.len() < 5
   }
}

struct PrefixChecker {
   prefix: String,
}
impl Checker for PrefixChecker {
   fn check(&self, value: &str) -> bool {
      value.starts_with(self.prefix)
   }
}

fn check(value: &str, which: &str) -> bool {
   let checker = if which == "short" {
      ShortChecker { }
   } else if which == "prefix" {
      PrefixChecker { prefix: "xyzzy".to_string() }
   } else { 
      panic!("Unknown option");
   };

   checker.check(value)
}
```

This fails to compile, since the different arms of the if statement return different types (`ShortChecker` vs. `PrefixChecker`).  All I need is that there is local variable of type `Checker`.  My first attempt at fixing it was

```
let checker: Checker = ...
```

which gave a warning that traits without `dyn` are deprecated.  So I tried

```
let checker: dyn Checker = ...
```

That fails with E0308 because

```
    = note: expected trait object `dyn Checker`
                     found struct `PrefixChecker`
```

If I was trying to store this in a struct to use later, I know I would need a `Box<dyn Checker>` (or `Rc` or ...).  Do I also need something like that for a local variable?  Since the variable is local, the compiler can reason about when it will go out of scope, so it seems that wrapping it could be unnecessary.

Is there a way to assign an object to a trait-typed local variable without wrapping it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Box`, but there's another neat trick you can use:

```rust
fn check(value: &str, which: &str) -> bool {
    let (short_checker, prefix_checker);
    let checker: &dyn Checker = if which == "short" {
        short_checker = ShortChecker {};
        &short_checker
    } else if which == "prefix" {
        prefix_checker = PrefixChecker {
            prefix: "xyzzy".to_string(),
        };
        &prefix_checker
    } else {
        panic!("Unknown option");
    };

    checker.check(value)
}
```

Comment: That's amazingly clever. I always forget the fun little tricks you can do with uninitialized variables.

Comment: Interesting.  Although it will get a bit verbose if (as I expect) the code eventually expands to 5-7 cases.

Comment: @TroyDaniels Maybe you can use a macro

Comment: Is the more general explanation here that I can have `&dyn SomeTrait` but not `dyn SomeTrait` as my outermost type?  So I need something reference-like (`Box`, `Rc`, `&`, ...) as an outer layer?

Comment: @TroyDaniels Yes. Though there was an RFC for unsized rvalues, I don't think it will be stabilized soon, or in the current form.

Comment: @TroyDaniels The reason for that is that `dyn SomeTrait` can have any size, for instance if it's `ShortChecker` it has size 0 and if `PrefixChecker` then 24 bytes on a 64 machine (3 `usize`s for `String`), so the compiler doesn't know the amount of size to allocate on stack.